# How to handle “CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed(-9807)” in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, cfnetwork

I am getting **CFNetwork SSL Handshake failed(-9807)** in my ios application while logging into application.

I am using Xcode version 7.3 for my application.
I think this problem occurs due to expired ssl certificates, but I am not able to handle the problem and I don't able to figure out where to put this ssl certificates in the application.

Can U please suggest me some solution??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when I get CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed -(*) It's because of my wifi network or due to Security reason firewall block the connection.

Try it again on another network.